# Derivative of the integral involving an inverse as a limit

Tags: integration, derivatives

can someone help with finding the derivative of the following.
$$\int_{0.5}^{\cot(x)} cot^{-1}(z) dz $$
I think we have to use the fundamental theorem of calculus part 2. But I'm unsure as the upper limit is in terms of x while the function is in terms of z.

Comment: [Leibniz Integral Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Formal_statement)

Comment: do you know how to differentiate $cot^{-1}$ ?  You can use the product rule on 1  $cot^{-1}$   -  integrating the 1 to get $x / (1 + x^2)$ to integrate  if you are lucky

Comment: here do you see it http://www.themathpage.com/acalc/inverse-trig.htm#arccot, the derivative of arccot seems to go nicely with the integral of '1' - try the product rule

Comment: $(\int\limits_a^{g(x)} f(t)dt)'=f(g(x))g'(x)$

Answer (score 1):

The Fundamental Theorem is sometimes best understood if you just pretend to know the anti-derivative.  Say $F^{\prime}(x) = \cot^{-1} x$.  Then $$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{o.5}^{\cot x}\cot^{-1}x \; dx = \frac{d}{dx} (F(\cot x) - F(0.5)) =
F^{\prime}(\cot x) - 0$$ $$ = \cot^{-1}(\cot x)\frac{d}{dx}(\cot x) = -x\csc^2(x).$$

Comment: Don't forget the chain rule. :-)

Comment: @user90369  Details...details...OK. I'll fix it....

Answer (score 0):

Using Leibniz Integral Rule, we get:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\int_\text{a}^{f(x)}y(z)\space\text{d}z\right)=y\left(f(x)\right)\cdot f'(x)$$

So, we get:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\cot(x)}\text{arccot}(z)\space\text{d}z\right)=\text{arccot}\left(\cot(x)\right)\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\cot(x)\right)=-\csc^2(x)\text{arccot}\left(\cot(x)\right)$$